# How to go back two times in freagments

Tags: android-fragments

I have three fragments f1,f2,f3.
f1 contain a list click select a item from list then fragment f2 loads it again contain another list. select a item from list fragment f3 gets loaded.
this fragment f3 contain 3 button.
Button 1 again open a new fragment.
button 2 for go back to f2 fragment.
button 3 for go back to f1 fragment.

I want to know how to go back from f3 to f1 if i click on button 3 in fragment f3???

Comment: Please include your code in the question otherwise it holds no value to the community.

Comment: i will keep this in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a good sample or tutorial. So start with this webpage @ [Google Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity). Search for "here's how you can replace one fragment with another...". Code snippet from the webpage:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Notice the **replace** method. Afterwards post code and layouts.
Good luck and have fun...